# I need to take an object as an argument and return all values and keys

Tags: javascript, object

I need to write a function called `printObj()` that takes an object as an argument and console logs each key along with its value on separate lines.

```js
let computer = {
    brand: 'Lenovo',
    cpu: 'i7',
    price: 12000
}


function printObj(arg) {
return computer

}
printObj(computer)
```

However this returns an object

```js
/*This is how is is being returned*/ 
*******************************************
 printObj(computer)

{brand: "Lenovo", cpu: "i7", price: 12000}
*******************************************
/*I need it to be returnd in the console like this*/
****************************************
 printObj(computer) 

//brand: Lenovo
//cpu: i7
//price: 12000

//Each on its own line
```

Please help out

Comment: What do you have tried so far ? It looks like a school exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code as follows:

```
let computer = {
    brand: 'Lenovo',
    cpu: 'i7',
    price: 12000
}

function printObj(arg) {
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(arg)) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
  }
}

printObj(computer)
```

Or simply as follows by using `console.log` instead of `return` to print it on console with your desired formatting:

```
let computer = {
    brand: 'Lenovo',
    cpu: 'i7',
    price: 12000
}

function printObj(arg) {
  console.log(arg);
}

printObj(computer)
```

Comment: Can you please provide a alternate solution as well @abdullahkhawer?

Comment: Where are you executing the code? NodeJS server or something else?

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `Object.entries()`. That will give you an array of arrays. Each child array has the `key` at the 0th index, and the value at the 1st index.

For reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Answer (score 2):

First, if you want to write to the console, use the console.log() method in your function instead of returning the value. For iterating over the keys in an object you can use the `for..in` statement, and inside the loop access the values with the bracket notation.

```
function printObj(obj) {
    for(let key in obj) {
        console.log(`${key}: ${obj[key]}`);
    }
}
```

`for...in` [Statement Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)